# Generate a number between 0 and 4 and excluding one number

Tags: c

in the following code, is there a better way to exclude a value in the random ?

```
    enum Direction {HAUT, BAS, GAUCHE, DROITE} direction;

switch(direction)
{
    case HAUT:
        if (false)
        {
        do{direction=(rand() % 4); }while(direction!=0); 
        break;
        }

    case BAS:
        if (false)
        {
        do{direction=(rand() % 4); }while(direction!=1);
        break;
        }          
    case GAUCHE:
..........
```

Comment: I did not quite get the `if(false)` part. What is it for?

Comment: (it keeps it from doing anything at all....)

Comment: I replaced a whole line of code with a simple false if ((ennemi->y - 1 < 0)||(carte[ennemi->x][ennemi->y - 1] == MUR)||(carte[ennemi->x][ennemi->y - 1] == BOMBE))

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your code always excludes the current direction (up excludes 0, down excludes 1, and so on), so you can use `Enum.ordinal` to decide the exclusion rather than using the switch, like this:

```
Direction direction = GAUCHE; // ...for example...
int nextDir;
do {
    nextDir = rand() % 4;
} while (nextDir == direction);
direction = nextDir;
```

Comment: @Jack No - I started answering thinking it's Java, then switched to C midway, except for the first line :) It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
new_direction = rand() % 3;
direction = (new_direction < direction) ? new_direction : new_direction + 1;
```

If the direction we generate is less than the number we wish to exclude, keep it.  Otherwise increase by 1 to skip the excluded number.  The range of the random number is accordingly reduced by 1.